# Why my cron routine doesn't work

Tags: cron

When I put

```
* * * * * /var/www/script.sh
```

Script is executed once per minute, but if I put

```
* */2 * * * /var/www/script.sh
```

instead, script doesn't execute at all

Comment: How long did you wait? `* */2 * * *` would mean every minute of every even hour (i.e. when the hour is divisible by 2) - it won't run at all if the hour is odd

Comment: I want it to run once per hour. I was waiting one day now.

Comment: You could send the full output to a log file like this `* */2 * * * /var/www/script.sh  >> /path/to/file.log 2>&1`. That way you can see if there's any permission issue, and/or a bash programing one.

Comment: For "once per hour", just change the first `*` to any valid minute (from 0-59) and leave the hour field as `*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to change the '*' out for the number. Therefore your second asterix should be 2 so:

```
* 2 * * * /var/www/script.sh
```

and not

```
* */2 * * * /var/www/script.sh
```

For future reference 
The first asterisk is for specifying the minute of the run (0-59)
The second asterisk is for specifying the hour of the run (0-23)
The third asterisk is for specifying the day of the month for the run (1-31)
The fourth asterisk is for specifying the month of the run (1-12)
The fifth asterisk is for specifying the day of the week (where Sunday is equal

Comment: I guess it's correct if You want to run script at 2am everyday, but i want my script to run once per hour/two hours

Comment: Ok so you are correct with the syntax. and I am guessing you waited 2 hours to check right ? AS what you are doing is to run cron minute after every 2 hours. Is there nothing in syslog as for the execution of the script ?

Comment: How can i check it?

Comment: Try this one: 1 */2 * * *

Comment: This should run it every 1 minute every 2 hours and wait

Comment: @kubawich To be clear: `1 */2 * * *` runs at e.g. 08:01, 10:01, 12:01, 14:01, 16:01 etc. Maybe you find [_crontab guru_](https://crontab.guru/#1_*/2_*_*_*) helpful.

Comment: I wonder why this is the accepted answer. The OP said [_"I want it to run once per hour."_](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111679/why-my-cron-routine-doesnt-work#comment1834905_1111679) and `* 2 * * *` runs it ***every single minute*** from 2AM to 2:59AM. Completely different cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to run every **hour**, then you need a number in the minute field. To run it at quarter past the hour, for example, use:

```
15 * * * * /var/www/script.sh
```

From `man -i 5 crontab`:

```
   Commands are executed by cron(8) when the minute, hour, and month of year fields match the  current
   time,  and when at least one of the two day fields (day of month, or day of week) match the current
   time (see ``Note'' below).  cron(8) examines cron entries once every minute.   The  time  and  date
   fields are:

          field          allowed values
          -----          --------------
          minute         0-59
          hour           0-23
          day of month   1-31
          month          1-12 (or names, see below)
          day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)

   A field may be an asterisk (*), which always stands for ``first-last''.

   Ranges  of  numbers  are  allowed.   Ranges are two numbers separated with a hyphen.  The specified
   range is inclusive.  For example, 8-11 for an ``hours'' entry specifies execution at hours 8, 9, 10
   and 11.

   Lists  are  allowed.   A  list  is  a  set  of  numbers (or ranges) separated by commas.  Examples:
   ``1,2,5,9'', ``0-4,8-12''.

   Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a range with ``/<number>'' specifies
   skips  of  the  number's value through the range.  For example, ``0-23/2'' can be used in the hours
   field to specify command execution every  other  hour  (the  alternative  in  the  V7  standard  is
   ``0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22'').  Steps are also permitted after an asterisk, so if you want to
   say ``every two hours'', just use ``*/2''.
```